# I wanna learn how to load images in Asynctask way and load those in listViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, listadapter, loadimage

everybody,
I get a problem that I use a listView to show hundreds of images from my local resources,and I set the image full of screen.There is a item with a imageView and a TextView in each list item.But when I slide to the next item ,it's not smoothly .I use the ImageFactory.options to adjust the scale of images.But the problem still exists.I guess maybe I should use asynctask loading and image cache to fix this problem.
here is my code,hope you buddies point my problems.Thank you very much.

```
package com.jafir.project.adapter;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.jafir.project.porunacabeza.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView.RecyclerListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PicListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private Context context;
    private Resources resources;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> list;
    public PicListViewAdapter(Context context,List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        resources = context.getResources();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pic, null);
            holder =  new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_pic);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pic);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        int resID = (Integer) list.get(position).get("image");
        String text = (String) list.get(position).get("text");
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeBitmap(resources, resID, holder.imageView.getWidth(),          holder.imageView.getHeight()));
        holder.textView.setText(text);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeBitmap(Resources res,int id,int width,int height){
        BitmapFactory.Options  options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,id,options);
        options.inSampleSize = getInSampleSize(options,width,height);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,id,options);
    }

    public int getInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,int reqWidth,int reqHeight){
        final int width  = options.outWidth;
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            int radioWidth = Math.round((float)width/(float)reqWidth);
            int radioHeight = Math.round((float)height/(float)reqHeight);
            inSampleSize = radioHeight < radioWidth ?radioHeight:radioWidth;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

      final static class ViewHolder{
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView textView;
        }
}
```

this is for activity:

```
 private void init() {
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lst_pic);
        list = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        for(int i=0;i < texts.length;i++){
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("image", R.drawable.img0+ i);
            map.put("text", texts[i]);
            list.add(map);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new PicListViewAdapter(getActivity(), list));
    }
```

this is for item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use that list adapter but within it use the [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library to load the image. Picasso does not load images on the UI thread. That is why you are receiving this error. After adding the library, try making your `getView()` like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pic, null);
        holder =  new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_pic);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pic);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    int resID = (Integer) list.get(position).get("image");
    String text = (String) list.get(position).get("text");
    //Picasso code
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
    Picasso picasso = builder.build();
    picasso.load(resID).into(holder.imageView);
    //End Picasso code
    holder.textView.setText(text);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks almyz125 ,is there the link of the picasso library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comprehensive guide on Android official site, please refer it at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

The session contains the following topics:

**Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently**
This lesson walks you through decoding large bitmaps without exceeding the per application memory limit.

**Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread**
Bitmap processing (resizing, downloading from a remote source, etc.) should never take place on the main UI thread. This lesson walks you through processing bitmaps in a background thread using AsyncTask and explains how to handle concurrency issues.

**Caching Bitmaps**
This lesson walks you through using a memory and disk bitmap cache to improve the responsiveness and fluidity of your UI when loading multiple bitmaps.

**Managing Bitmap Memory**
This lesson explains how to manage bitmap memory to maximize your app's performance.

**Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI**
This lesson brings everything together, showing you how to load multiple bitmaps into components like ViewPager and GridView using a background thread and bitmap cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. I've tested the implementation using the ViewRenderer (https://gist.github.com/tomgibara/1084229) from tomgibara maybe 2 years before, resulting in very smooth output. It's well

If I will try to give it a shot, I'll try to create a mechanism by myself.
Some consideration for your reference:

- Put the decoded bitmap into LRUCache so that you will not get a
  OutOfMemoryError. Seriously, this is probable when you are loading a
  lot of images.
- Use AsyncTask/Loader/Raw Thread as you like. No much
  difference in essence.